# Start google maps android app with waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm building a website with a button. When I hit the button on a tablet or smartphone the google maps android app should be starting with a direction, which is set on the website.
With one source and one destination address it's not a problem. For this I can use:

```
google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

[Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

But I need to start the navigation with multiple waypoints.
Is there also a possiblity to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean a list of waypoints like this:

[image]

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-examples-using-waypoints) to the sample

Comment: yes, but this opens the regular web app with waypoints. I want to open the Google Maps android app on the tablet with waypoints.